# Key error when retrieving nested JSON data

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse some JSON data relating to currency conversion rates which is nested.

I wish to retrieve the "rate" data in the following JSON response:

```
 "info": {
    "timestamp": 1519328414,
    "rate": 148.972231
},
```

I am using Django and in my view I do the following to attempt to retrieve the "rate" data in the JSON response:

```
import requests

def currency_convert_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        from_ = request.session.get('currency', "USD")
        to_ = request.POST.get('currency')

        if to_:
            response = requests.get(CURRENCY_BASE_URL +
                "convert?access_key=" + CURRENCY_ACCESS_KEY +
                "&from=" + from_ +
                "&to=" + to_ +
                "&amount=1"
            )
            json_response = response.json()
            conversion_rate = json_response["info"]["rate"]

            accounts = Account.objects.filter(sold=False).order_by('-price')
            prices = [{
                "price": a.price * conversion_rate,
            } for a in accounts]

            return JsonResponse({
                "prices": price,
                "currency": to_,
            })
    return redirect("home")
```

But upon attempting to access this data using `json_response["info"]["rate"]`, I get the following error.

```
conversion_rate = json_response["info"]["rate"]
KeyError: 'info'
```

How can I fix this such that I retrieve the rate data nested within info?

Comment: first check if `json_response` is actually getting `info` key?

Comment: lol, {u'success': False, u'error': {u'info': u'Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support this API Function.', u'code': 105, u'type': u'function_access_restricted'}} so I need to upgrade my plan i guess?...

Comment: if it says so :D